# Adding a grouped, aggregate nunique column to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I want to add an aggregate, grouped, nunique column to my pandas dataframe but not aggregate the entire dataframe. I'm trying to do this in one line and avoid creating a new aggregated object and merging that, etc.

my df has track, type, and id. I want the number of unique ids for each track/type combination as a new column in the table (but not collapse track/type combos in the resulting df). Same number of rows, 1 more column.

something like this isn't working:

```
df['n_unique_id'] = df.groupby(['track', 'type'])['id'].nunique()
```

nor is

```
df['n_unique_id'] = df.groupby(['track', 'type'])['id'].transform(nunique)
```

this last one works with some aggregating functions but not others. the following works (but is meaningless on my dataset):

```
df['n_unique_id'] = df.groupby(['track', 'type'])['id'].transform(sum)
```

in R this is easily done in data.table with

```
df[, n_unique_id := uniqueN(id), by = c('track', 'type')]
```

thanks!

Comment: Can paste a copy of your source dataframe and what the expected output should look like?

Answer (score 6):

```
df.groupby(['track', 'type'])['id'].transform(nunique)
```

Implies that there is a name `nunique` in the name space that performs some function.  `transform` will take a function or a string that it knows a function for.  `nunique` is definitely one of those strings.

As pointed out by @root, often the method that `pandas` will utilize to perform a transformation indicated by these strings are optimized and should generally be preferred to passing your own functions.  This is `True` even for passing `numpy` functions in some cases.

For example `transform('sum')` should be preferred over `transform(sum)`.

Try this instead

```
df.groupby(['track', 'type'])['id'].transform('nunique')
```

***demo***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    track=list('11112222'), type=list('AAAABBBB'), id=list('XXYZWWWW')))
print(df)

  id track type
0  X     1    A
1  X     1    A
2  Y     1    A
3  Z     1    A
4  W     2    B
5  W     2    B
6  W     2    B
7  W     2    B

df.groupby(['track', 'type'])['id'].transform('nunique')

0    3
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I was just about to comment with this.  It might be useful to mention that the string aliases should usually be preferred if available, as they'll reference optimal functions, e.g. `.transform(sum)` uses python `sum`, whereas `.transfrom('sum')` would use numpy and be more computationally efficient.