# Select distinct values groupby column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code `df1 = df.groupby(['ID_Customer', 'ID_product']).size()`
for calculation of number of rows for each product for each customer. There is one single row for each product for each customer in dataset. The result is the following df1 (part of)

```
    ID cust    ID prod   
    026        009               30
    027        009               1
    028        009               15
    030        009               30
    032        009               30
    ...
```

How to calculate the number of distinct product per customer? Or how to implement select distinct values groupby column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a grouped, aggregate nunique column to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726631/adding-a-grouped-aggregate-nunique-column-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this below code:

```
df.groupby('ID_Customer')['ID_product'].count()
```

let me know if this works for you or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df.groupby(['ID_Customer'])['ID_product'].nunique()
```

Comment: didn't get your question. you want to filter the df ?

Comment: Uh I tried to calculate number of changes and first seemed to me that this will solve the problem but I am not shure any more. I will post other question with example to find the solution